# Overload ambiguity with boost::optional, workaround?

Tags: c++, boost, overloading, deprecated, boost-optional

I would like to overload with boost::optional but cannot due to overload ambiguity and am looking for a workaround.

For example, the following code will not compile due to ambiguity:

```cpp
void foo() { ... }
void foo(const Class& A) { ... }
// \deprecated
void foo(boost::optional<const Class&> A) { A ? foo(A) : foo() }
```

The reason I want to do this strange thing is because, due to bugs that have arisen from rvalue/lvalue issues with boost::optional, I am replacing boost::optional instances with function overloads instead.  The problem is that some API breakages occur so I need to leave the old function definitions deprecated.

An example of API breakages is with other default parameters,

```cpp
void foo(int a=0, boost::optional<Bar> A=boost::none, float b=0.0) { ... }
```

requires me to switch the order of arguments:

```cpp
void foo(int a=0, float b=0.0) { ... }
void foo(Bar A, int a=0, float b=0.0) { ... }
```

but now the case that breaks is
`foo(1, boost::none, 3.14);` so I want to keep a deprecated function definition just for this type of function call.  Is there an elegant workaround?

I suppose one (ugly) possibility is

```cpp
// \deprecated
void foo(int a, boost::optional<DummyClass> A, float b=0.0) { ... }
```

but this does not spark joy.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `void foo(boost::optional<const Class&> A) { A ? foo(*A) : foo() }`?  Second, `foo(int a=0, boost::optional<Bar> A, float b=0.0)` is not legal C++, you cannot have a non-defaulted argument after a defaulted one.

Comment: regarding Adam's second comment, yes my mistake, edited question accordingly;
@Jarod42 sorry I'm not familiar with deprecated require or `=delete`, could you elaborate or provide a resource for reference?

Comment: No I meant, do you really need the deprecated function, or marking it as deleted to forbid its usage is enough (`void foo(boost::optional<const Class&> A) = delete;`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh I see - unfortunately existing code already passes the `boost::none` argument so deleting the function would break other people's code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As state in comment, your regular case has typo which does recursive call. Fixed version:

```
void foo() { /*...*/ }
void foo(const Class& A) { /*...*/ }

[[deprecated]] void foo(boost::optional<const Class&> A) { A ? foo(*A) : foo(); }
```

> I am replacing `boost::optional` instances with function overloads instead.

So you might replace:

```
void foo(int a=0, boost::optional<Bar> A=boost::none, float b=0.0) { /*...*/ }
```

By

```
void foo(int a = 0) {/*..*/}
void foo(int a, Bar, float b = 0.0f) { /*..*/ }
void foo(int a, boost::none_t, float b = 0.0f) { /*..*/ }

[[deprecated]] void foo(int a, boost::optional<Bar>, float b = 0.0f);
```